# What is flow wake mode?

Tags: javascript, facebook, flowtype

What is flow `wake` mode?

```
// @flow wake
... ... ...
```

I started work with flow few weeks ago. I saw `@flow wake` three days ago, but I'm not sure when and where to use it.

Please help me! :-)

Comment: Looks like just a comment to me. I haven't heard of something like _wake_ for flow

Answer (score 2):

It's not a thing. I just searched the codebase to be sure and found nothing about "wake" mode.

Probably, somebody misspelled "weak." Weak mode basically means that missing annotations are treated as `any` (no type checking).